# Последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем

Tags: python, for, while

1. Дана непустая последовательность целых чисел, оканчивающаяся нулем.

Найти:

- сумму всех чисел последовательности;
- количество всех чисел последовательности.

Решить задачу используя циклическую конструкцию for.

2. Дано целое число N (> 1).

Найти:

- наибольшее целое число K, при котором выполняется неравенство 2^K > N.

Решить задачу используя циклическую конструкцию while.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: решение второй задачи всегда будет бесконечность

Answer (score 1):

1. найти сумму через функцию `sum`
2. найти кол-во чисел через функцию `len`
3. найти максимальное через функцию `max`
4. сформировать последовательность с нулями через конструкцию `arr_new = [i for in arr_old <условие>]` или через функцию `filter`
5. последовательность оканчивающуюся нулями можно определить через модуль `x % 10 == 0`